# Print alphabet using javascript

Tags: javascript

My code is only giving the last letter eg: `i < 90;` it gives only letter 'z'

```
<body>
    <div id="div1" ></div>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        for (i = 65; i < 99; i++) {
            var str[]=String.fromCharCode(i);
            $("#div1").html("str");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is wrong with your currrent implementation?

Comment: its only giving the last letter eg: i<90; its gives only letter 'z'

Comment: Is it? I thought you are getting 33 "str"s? Please add some code, so we can reproduce your issue. What is `var str[]`? It's not JS?

Comment: ok, give me one min

Comment: <body>
  <div id="div1" ></div>

   <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

  <script>

for (i = 65; i < 99; i++) { 
 var str[]=String.fromCharCode(i);

$("#div1").html("str");
} 
  
  </script>
 </body>

Comment: [Edit] the question to give a [mcve]. Read [ask].

Comment: You're not getting anything with this code, `str[]` is a syntax error, `[` and `]` are not valid characters in variable names.

Comment: *"... its gives only letter 'z'"* So in other words, this isn't your code at all, and you just threw together an example that you assumed was useful.

Comment: Hmm ... Was my edit vandalism? It seems that "Unable to run this code" was the correct problem description after all?.

Comment: @Teemu: Not your fault if the OP is contradicting himself.

Comment: You need to use a closure. As `str` will always be the last character.

Comment: Well, the edit doesn't matter anymore, we have a copy-paste-run-be-happy-answer, once again ... @evolutionbox What???

Comment: Variables are not block scoped. The loop will overwrite the str variable and update the HTML on each iteration. To stop this you need to use a closure

Comment: ??? "To stop this" we need `+=`, or `.append`, really no need for a closure. Not a callback or async code here.

Comment: i have already posted answer using append @Teemu

Comment: @Chetan Yeah, it was working, you just "fixed" it incorrectly ...

Comment: @Teemu -need text function instead of append right??

Comment: THANKS... ALL..WAS USEFUL

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```html
<body>
  <div id="div1" ></div>
  <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    for (i = 65; i < 99; i++) {
      var tmpVal =   $("#div1").text();
      var str =String.fromCharCode(i);
      $("#div1").text(tmpVal+" "+str);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This will overwrite str constantly. This will not have the desired effect.

Comment: hmmm...@evolutionxbox, got it.

Comment: Good. Will you be updating your answer?